# I WANT procmail to delay one user's e-mail 10 seconds then continue processing

Tags: filter, procmail, delay

I use procmail.  I wrote my own spam filter in procmail (along with many many recipes).

I know this is sounds counter-intuitive but I **want** to intentionally delay one user's e-Mail about 5 or 10 seconds while a dynamic spam filter procmail recipe can get populated.

I don't want procmail processing to stop or exit after the delay.  I want this e-mail to be delayed in the middle of the recipes, then proceed through the rest of the procmail recipes after being delayed.  I want this delay to happen in-line in the middle of the long list of procmail recipes.  I don't want to stop or slow other users' e-mails through the procmail filter, only this one user.  There may be several (probably spam) e-mails proceeding through the filter at once and I don't want to delay them because I use them to fill a recipe.

My procmail is on a shared hosting machine.  This is a single userID (me) domain and I use multiple e-mail addresses for myself.

Answer (score 3):

Just Do It.

```
dummyvalue=`sleep 10`
```

If you want it as part of a recipe, you can easily run any command synchronously:

```
:0w
* ? sleep 10
{ }
```

(I added the `w` flag for good measure.)

Much larger values are possible, though if you exceed the default value of `TIMEOUT`, Procmail will abort the sleep.  Though you can bump the value of `TIMEOUT` to a larger value (the default is 960 seconds).

Comment: I am making an attempt, this doesn't make errors, trying:# =========================
# Slow down by 10 seconds larry's e-Mail before ACTIVE IP FILTER

:0 w
* larry
* ? sleep 10
{ }

# =================================================

Comment: That didn't come out so well.  You can't use source formatting in comments, unfortunately.  What's with the "larry" anyway?  Here's a quick demo: http://pastebin.com/DaftBUe1

Comment: Thank You Tripleee!  You nailed the solution, it seems to be working just fine.  Larry is a dummy user on this system.  I did put * larry@ on the first line after the :0 w and I have had no unusual spam coming to larry today, the delay worked.  I'm marking this as solved, the fix is in.  If you want more details you can contact me by e-mail and I can tell you exactly what I did, but it is too long to post here.

Comment: I don't see an email address on your profile page. Once you have the required 20 reputation points, why don't you invite me to chat? (See link at the bottom of this page.)

Comment: @tripleee - you can use `source code formatting in comments` .. you just need to use paired backticks :)

Comment: @warren There is (obviously) limited support, but in contexts where newlines are significant, you are basically SOL. You can use `tricks` / `like this` to suggest where the newlines go, but in the end, comments are just not made for this.